# How to remove CSS properties if the values are “none” or “0”?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this case I would need to remove `top`, `background-image`, and `background-color`:

```
<div id="div1" style="position: relative; font-size: 24px; left: 175px; width: 400px; height: 200px; top: 0; background-image: none; background-color: none; background-position: 50% 50%;" > New Element </div>
```

Comment: To change a CSS after the page has been loaded, you need to use some javascript code. Can you show us what have you tried do far with javascript?

Answer (score 2):

you can change style attribute

```
jQuery('#div1').attr('style','position: relative; font-size: 24px; left: 175px; width: 400px; height: 200px;  background-position: 50% 50%;')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** with callback to update inline css

```js
$('#div1').attr('style', function(i, v) {
  return v.split(';')
  // split css value by `;` to get each property
  .filter(function(val) {
    // filtering values
    var str = $.trim(val.split(':')[1]);    
    // getting property value and trimming to avoid spaces
    return !(str == 0 || str == 'none' || str == ''); 
    // checking property value is 0, none or '' , based on this filtering is done
  }).join(';');
  // joining splitted array and return back for updating style property
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="position: relative; font-size: 24px; left: 175px; width: 400px; height: 200px; top: 0; background-image: none; background-color: none; background-position: 50% 50%;">New Element</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `css()` with empty string or invalid values  will remove those from style attribute

```
$('#div1').each(function () {
    var $el = $(this),
        top = $el.css('top'),
        bgImg = $el.css('backgroundImage'),
        bgColor = $el.css('backgroundColor');       

        $el.css({
            top: top && top === '0px' ? '' : top,
            backgroundImage :bgImg =='none' ?'' : bgImg,
            backgroundColor:bgColor =='none' ?'' : bgColor
        });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o46eu20w/)**</kbd>